# При уникальном имени, не бросать исключение DuplicateEntry, а взять уже существующий

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Можно ли при добавлении объекта, без дополнительного поиска вставить индекс на существующий объект, если его имя должно быть уникальным?

Т.е.:

```
public class SerialInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TitleOriginal { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Uri PreviewImageUri { get; set; }
    public bool IsMovie { get; set; }
    public uint? SeriesCount { get; set; }
    public uint? CurrentSeriesCount { get; set; }
    public virtual Studio Studio { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SerialGenre> Genres { get; set; }
    public FullSerialInfo FullInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Где к примеру у поля `Studio` уникальное имя, т.е. не должно быть дубликатов, и когда при попытке добавления сериала, такая студия уже существует, то получается исключение:

> MySqlException: Duplicate entry 'Some StudioName' for key
>   'IX_Producers_Name'

Можно ли без поиска студии сделать так, что бы если она уже есть, просто добавился ее ключ?

На данный момент, все это делаю вот так:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<SerialInfo>> PostSerialInfo(SerialInfo serialInfo)
{
    if (SerialInfoExists(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(serialInfo.Title, serialInfo.TitleOriginal),
        out SerialInfo fInfo))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("GetSerialInfo", new {id = fInfo.Id});
    }

    Studio existingStudio = _context.Studios.FirstOrDefault(studio =>
        string.Equals(serialInfo.Studio.Name.Trim(), studio.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    Producer existingProducer = _context.Producers.FirstOrDefault(producer =>
        string.Equals(serialInfo.FullInfo.Producer.Name.Trim(), producer.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

    if (existingStudio != null)
    {
        serialInfo.Studio = existingStudio;
    }

    if (existingProducer != null)
    {
        serialInfo.FullInfo.Producer = existingProducer;
    }

    _context.Serials.Add(serialInfo);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction("GetSerialInfo", new {id = serialInfo.Id}, serialInfo);
}
```

Comment: Можно сделать `Studio.Name` первичным ключом (убрать `Id`). Тогда будет желаемое поведение.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Это по бизнес-логике не пройдёт. Типа, "студии одного сериала"

Comment: Вы всё делаете правильно и упростить здесь нельзя. Если вы делаете подобные вставки из экселя и чего-то ещё - увы, но нет. Базе нужна целостность foreign ключей, вы её аккуратно создаёте, методично обрабатывая все данные. Если у вас какой-то UI - то обычно всё это делается путём указания в html'ом select'е id и value, там попроще и меньше проверок делать.

Comment: Почему же? У студии и в этом случае может быть множество сериалов. Просто тип первичного ключа другой.

Comment: А впрочем, нет, и в этом случае нужно сперва находить нужную студию. EF по умолчанию попытается вставить новую студию. Увы.

Comment: Вижу проблему в коде: поиск существующей студии будет происходить на клиенте. Похоже, нужно создать вопрос на эту тему и написать ответ. Распространённая проблема.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: `EF по умолчанию попытается вставить новую студию.` Как я понимаю, это поведение нельзя никак переопределить?

Comment: Думаю, никак. Сейчас сделано правильно: сперва ищем существующую студию, потом добавляем.

Comment: [Как сделать логирование запросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1005530/184217). Использовал именно ваш запрос для примера.