# Просмотр/логирование сгенерированных запросов

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

В обычном Entity Framework очень легко реализовать просмотр сгенерированных sql-запросов:

```
using (var context = new SomeContext())
{
    context.Database.Initialize(false);
    context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;
    //...
}
```

В результате в консоль будет выводиться sql и можно оценить получившийся запрос. Первая строка нужна, чтобы исключить код инициализации контекста.

Как сделать логирование в Entity Framework Core?

Comment: На en so нет подобных топиков? А то может и ассоциацию проставить?

Comment: @AK - похожих вопросов много. Не знаю, какой выбрать для ассоциации.

Comment: Наиболее близкий и свежий, а то я вот начал смотреть - и вижу кучу вопросов древних годов, когда core ещё цифру 7 носил в названии. И советы везде разные, так что чем ближе ответ "тут и там" - тем лучше.

Comment: @AK - пожалуй, это подходит: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26747837/5045688

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Опишу самый простой способ.

Устанавливаем пакет:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console
```

В классе контекста добавляем фабрику логгера и регистрируем её.

```
public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseLoggerFactory(loggerFactory);
    }

    static readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory().AddConsole(LogLevel.Information);
}
```

Всё, после этого можно лицезреть в консоли сгенерированные запросы.

`LogLevel.Information` убирает большую часть сообщений, которые обычно не нужны. Задайте нужный вам уровень.

---

Я только начал освоение EF Core, но мне сразу же стали попадаться множество примеров кода, которые генерируют запросы, в итоге выполняющиеся на клиенте, а не на сервере.

Вообще, EF Core известен тем, что оказывает медвежью услугу разработчикам: если он не может что-либо выполнить на сервере СУБД, он вытягивает *все* данные из базы данных и продолжает обработку уже на клиенте. Обычный EF в таком случае бросал исключение. В [EF Core 3.0](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) будет сделано такое же поведение.

---

Например, вот такой запрос:

```
var serialInfo = new SerialInfo { Studio = new Studio { Name = "Aaa" } };

Studio existingStudio = context.Studios.FirstOrDefault(studio =>
    string.Equals(serialInfo.Studio.Name.Trim(), studio.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

порождает вывод следующих сообщений:

```
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 2.2.6-servicing-10079 initialized 'SomeContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
.SqlServer' with options: None

warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'where Equals(__Trim_0, [studio].Name, InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)' could not be translated an
d will be evaluated locally.

warn: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[20500]
      The LINQ expression 'FirstOrDefault()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (43ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [studio].[Name]
      FROM [Studios] AS [studio]
```

Тут можно видеть два предупреждения "could not be translated and will be evaluated locally" - это плохо. Запрос нужно переписать.

В конце мы видим сам sql-запрос. Понятно, что выгружается вся таблица полностью.

Comment: Может я что-то делаю не так, но у меня не появляется консоль :)

Comment: @ヒミコ - отладку запросов я делаю в консольном приложении. Вот в эту консоль и выводится всё.

Answer (score 0):

для Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=5

вывод в консоль только sql запоросов (требует using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;)

```
  optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, new[] { RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted });
```

и еще несколько вариантов:

```
  protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=relationsdb;Trusted_Connection=True;");

      //  optionsBuilder.LogTo(message => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message));
        optionsBuilder.LogTo(System.Console.WriteLine);
       // optionsBuilder.LogTo(Console.WriteLine, new[] { RelationalEventId.CommandExecuted });// только sql
    }
```